# How To Pass formdata parameters into ASP.NET WebAPI without creating a record structure

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have data coming into my form that looks like the image below (sessionsId: 1367,1368).

I've create c# in my webapi controller that works as below.  when I've tried ot just make use SessionIds as the parameter (or sessionIds) by saying something like PostChargeForSessions(string SessionIds) either null gets passed in or I get a 404.

What is the proper way to catch a form parameter like in my request without declaring a structure.

(the code below works, but I'm not happy with it)

```
    public class ChargeForSessionRec
    {
        public string SessionIds { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("ChargeForSessions")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostChargeForSessions(ChargeForSessionRec rec)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ShirtSizeReturn()
        {
            Success = true,
            //Data = shirtSizeRecs
        });
        return response;
    }
```

[image: headers]

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the action method like this.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string[] sessionIds) { }
```

If you don't want to define a class, the above code is the way to go. Having said that, the above code will not work with the request body you have. It must be like this.

```
=1381&=1380
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what code will work with the request body I have, not some other request body.

Comment: You can use FormDataCollection, like this: `public HttpResponseMessage Post(FormDataCollection data) { var sessionIds = data.GetValues("sessionIds"); }`. That's pretty much are the options, I guess.

Comment: Thanks Badri, I did not think of that.  That solution does work. I was hoping for something more type safe similar to my creating a class and referencing the property.  I had thought there might be some magic "frombody" type syntax that would allow me to do what I want without creating an extra public class